# How to Parameterize a Nested JSON request body in Rest assured framework?

Tags: json, nested, apache-poi

This is my request JSON body: 
{
    "Name":"SomeName",
    "Privileges": [

```
  {

        "PrivilegeName": "ABC"
    },
    {

        "PrivilegeName": "xyz"
    },
    {

        "PrivilegeName": "qwerty"
    }

]
```

}

I want to read data from excel and fill into json body inputs. eg abc.

If its a simple json body, i am able to read data from excel and fill it. I am using POJO concept to build my JSON body in rest assured framework?

Answer (score 1):

You should show what you have tried.

As you stated, you are using `POJO` concept to build `JSON`, `Jackson ObjectMapper` would be an option.

For example you could have following `POJO` classes:

```
import java.util.List; 
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class User {
 @JsonProperty("Name")
 private String name;
 @JsonProperty("Privileges")
 private List<Privilege> privileges;
 public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
 public String getName() { return this.name; }
 public void setPrivileges(List<Privilege> privileges) { this.privileges = privileges; }
 public List<Privilege> getPrivileges() { return this.privileges; }
}
```

and

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Privilege {
 @JsonProperty("PrivilegeName")
 private String privilegeName;
 public void setPrivilegeName(String privilegeName) { this.privilegeName = privilegeName; }
 public String getPrivilegeName() { return this.privilegeName; }
}
```

Then this `Jackson ObjectMapper` approach would create your `JSON`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class JacksonObjectMapperTest {

 private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

 public User createUser() {
  User user = new User();
  user.setName("SomeName");
  List<Privilege> privileges = new ArrayList<Privilege>();
  Privilege privilege = new Privilege(); privilege.setPrivilegeName("ABC");
  privileges.add(privilege);
  privilege = new Privilege(); privilege.setPrivilegeName("xyz");
  privileges.add(privilege);
  privilege = new Privilege(); privilege.setPrivilegeName("qwerty");
  privileges.add(privilege);
  user.setPrivileges(privileges);
  return user;
 }

 public String getJSONString(User user) throws Exception {
  String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
  return json;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  JacksonObjectMapperTest jOMT = new JacksonObjectMapperTest();
  User user = jOMT.createUser();
  System.out.println(jOMT.getJSONString(user));
 }
}
```